# In ASP.NET MVC 2, can you use data annotations to compare two fields in a form? What are the alternatives if not Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two fields in my form

AccountNumber
ReverseAccountNumber

Can i use data annotations to validate that the value of "ReverseAccountNumber" textbox is equal to the reversed value of "AccountNumber".

i.e.

AccountNumber = 12345
ReverseAccountNumber = 54321

i expect the validation to occur on the lostFocus event of the ReverseAccountNumber textbox.

I think i can do this using IDataErrorInfo, However I believe this would require a POST first before validation occurs, and i consider it a last resort.

Comment: why you not reverse automatically when accountNumber has lost focus.

Comment: @Adeel, the business rule is similar to some registration routines where you have to type in your email, then you have to type it in again to confirm. but the difference here is instead of just typing it in you'll have to do it backwards.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a validation attribute to the class (not the properties) and evaluate the class object to compare the two properties. As for the client side, ASP.NET MVC 3 should be able to generate proper client-side validation for this (although I have not tried it myself since Iam still using xVal).

Comment: sorry i haven't updated my app to ASP.NET MVC 3 yet so i'll have to go with ASP.NET MVC 2 solutions (will edit the problem). I'd like to try the Validation attribute to the class though, this calls for a CustomValidator correct? can you site some samples links that demonstrates this?

Comment: Yes, I've written a blog article about this: http://devermind.com/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-tip-4-client-side-form-validation-made-easy-part-2/ . Some of it refers to xVal, but the rest should be valid for your scenario as well.

Comment: i tried to make it work using data annotations instead of xVal. i'm not sure though how i could get the other value in the form. i got stuck in the part where i have to add validation parameters, should i be able to get the values of the "relevantProperties" in the Validator class?

Comment: i added my answer below. i found that your solution is still too complicated for me specially the javascripts. but you did lead me to the right direction. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

CustomAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ReversStringMatchAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string Property { get; set; }        

    public ReversStringMatchAttribute()
    { }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

CustomValidator

```
public class ReversStringValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<ReversStringMatchAttribute>
{
    string property;

    public ReversStringValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, ReversStringMatchAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        property = attribute.Property;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = Attribute.ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "reversStringValidator"
        };

        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("propertyname", property);

        return new[] { rule };
    }
}
```

Java Script

```
Sys.Mvc.ValidatorRegistry.validators["reversStringValidator"] = function (rule) {
//initialization

//return validator function
return function (value, context) {
    var field = $get(rule.ValidationParameters['propertyname']);
    if (field == null)
        return "Property name is invalid!";

    var s1 = field.value;

    if (s1) {
        if (value) {
            var reverse = value.split("").reverse().join("");
            if (s1 != reverse.toString()) {
                return rule.ErrorMessage;
            }
        } else {
            return rule.ErrorMessage;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

};

then use it on your property

```
public class AccountViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Account Number is Required")]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [ReversStringMatch(ErrorMessage = "The value doesn't match the Account Number", Property="AccountNumber")]
    public string ReverseAccountNumber { get; set; }            
}
```

i have some doubts on the $get validation method in javascript but it works, for now.