# ASP.NET MVC C# Data Annotations: Compare two values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am trying to create a data annotation for my MVC model to validate two dates. I have a start date and end date, the end date should be greater than the start date. I have managed to create an annotation but cannot pass values to it.
Does ayone have any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "pass values to it"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In ASP.NET MVC 2, can you use data annotations to compare two fields in a form? What are the alternatives if not Data Annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873615/in-asp-net-mvc-2-can-you-use-data-annotations-to-compare-two-fields-in-a-form)

Comment: Well, if I have two values, then surely passing the values to it would mean the following Method(valueone, valuetwo)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare a DateTime object another object of this type. If the startdate and endate are both DateTime objects the Compare method should do the trick.